# CPU cycles in Arduino uno for Digital read and counting pulses

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, pulse, cpu-cycles

I'm trying to count number of [HB100 microwave sensor](http://www.theorycircuit.com/hb100-microwave-motion-sensor-interfacing-arduino/) pulses in `200ms` time quanta.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <elapsedMillis.h>
elapsedMillis ElapsedTime;

#define Sensor A0
#define TimeQuanta 200

int Counter = 0;
boolean LastState;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(250000);
  pinMode(Sensor, INPUT);  
}

void loop()
{
  Counter = 0;
  ElapsedTime = 0;
  while (ElapsedTime < TimeQuanta ){
    LastState = digitalRead(Sensor);
    if (LastState == LOW && digitalRead(Sensor) == HIGH ){
      Counter += 1;  //Compare Last state with current state 
    }
  }
  Serial.print(digitalRead(Sensor));
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.println(Counter);
}
```

I need to know the digital read cycles.
I'm comparing the last state of the sensor with current state and if a change is made (LOW TO HIGH) the counter is incremented. However, my counter is always `0`!

- is the code correct (the `if` condition)?
- do I need some delays?
- is it possible to count these pulses?

Here is the *Logic Analyzer* output of *Microwave Sensor*:

[image]

---

Edit: if I add `delay(1);` before `if` then the counter is not 0 anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use timer1 to calculate the elapsed time.

```
// Set Timer1 without prescaler at CPU frequency
TCCR1A = 0; // TCCRx - Timer/Counter Control Register. The pre-scaler can be configured here. 
TCCR1B = 1;

noInterrupts ();  // Disable interrupts.

uint16_t  StartTime = TCNT1;  // TCNTx - Timer/Counter Register. The actual timer value is stored here.
digitalRead(pin); // your code.
uint16_t EndTime = TCNT1
uint16_t ElapsedTime = EndTime - StartTime;

interrupts (); //Enable interrupts.
```

As a second solution you can set and unset a pin and calculate the time with your Logic Analyzer.

```
DDRD = DDRD | B10000000; // Set digital pin 7 as output.
PORTD = PORTD | B10000000; // Set digital pin 7.
digitalRead(pin); // your code.
PORTD = PORTD & B01111111; // Unset digital pin 7.
```

Answer (score 3):

As these pulses seems to be even less than microsecond short, you just can't use `digitalRead` function that takes about 80 machine cycles (about 5us `@16MHz`).

Not to mention printing so many data in every single loop iteration!!!!

So you have frequencies over `1MHz` and your code might be able to count about `10kHz` (at best, maybe less)

Anyway, you should use HW `Timer/Counter 1` with clock source on `T1` input. This one is able to count pulses at the half of main clock rate (50% pulse width)

And using `Timer/Counter 1` is pretty simple:

```
TCCR1A = 0; // default mode, no output compare modes
TCCR1B = _BV(CS10) | _BV(CS11) | _BV(CS12); // clock select mode 7 - External clock source on T1 pin. Clock on rising edge.
```

And every 200ms just read  `TCNT1` and eventually reset to 0 or just remember last value and make difference (don't forget it's just 16b number).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, where can I find a document for CPU cycles for any operation?
The printings are out of while loop now.

Comment: Hardly, I was using my own "benchmark". But it's possible to toggle some output and measure the frequency. Maybe there are some articles on this topic somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

KIIV explained very well why your code doesn't work, here I would like to suggest an alternative approach that achieves the same goal.

---

Code:

```cpp
const byte interruptPin = 2;
volatile unsigned long counter = 0;                // overflow after 2^32-1 pulses

void setup() {
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), count, RISING);
  Serial.begin(19200);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("No. pulses: ");
  Serial.println(counter);
  delay(1000);
}

void count() {
  counter++;                                       // never use print() in an ISR!
}
```

Please note that **I changed the input pin**, because there are some [restrictions](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/attachInterrupt) on the pins that can be used with this technique which depend on the board you use:

```cpp
Board                                Digital Pins Usable For Interrupts
Uno, Nano, Mini, other               2, 3
Mega, Mega2560, MegaADK              2, 3, 18, 19, 20, 21
Micro, Leonardo, other 32u4-based    0, 1, 2, 3, 7
Zero                                 all digital pins, except 4
MKR1000 Rev.1                        0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A1, A2
Due, 101                             all digital pins
```

Comment: Thanks I'll read the mentioned document and test the code. I need to count pulses continuously in 200ms so Ithink  delay(1000) is not appropriate.

Comment: The delay is over the **print** function, the pulses are counted **continuosly** using the **interrupt service routine** `count()`. You can reduce the *delay*, but only up to a certain extent. Modern *Arduino* implementation uses *interrupts* to deal with `print()`, and this means that if you abuse of this instruction then you may miss *some pulses* or have other weird behaviour going on. Given the high frequency of your pulses, you certainly don't want to use `print()` after each and every pulse. Perhaps *every 100/1000 pulses* might be a better idea.

Comment: Your code is working. I Haven't used ISRs before, I'll should read more, thanks for your suggestion.